# Resize everything resting on an image on hover?

Tags: css, image, resize, hover

I'd post my code I've been trying to use to do this, but it's useless. I've got an image to resize a little on hover, but I want an image with text divs & other img divs that are on top of it to resize a little on hover & make all those other divs resize with it. I'd just Google my answers but I'm not even sure what are the proper terms for the search. Here's a simple example on Twitpic since I need more reputation to post images. It's an animated gif, we'll call the text "text", the camo background "camobg" & the moon landing pic "moon". [simple html/css hover example](http://twitpic.com/e60lb7)

If you want some extra credit, you can give me your thoughts on how to do the smoother javascript version of this. Here's another gif on Twitpic showing generally what I mean. [simple javascript hover example](http://twitpic.com/e60lkk)

Thanks in advance!!! :)

```
<div id="Image1" style="position:absolute;left:72px;top:176px;width:515px;height:250px;z-index:0;‌​"> 
    <img src="images/camobg.jpg" id="Image1" alt="" style="width:515px;height:250px;">
</div>
<div id="Image2" style="position:absolute;left:372px;top:205px;width:204px;height:200px;z-index:1‌​;"> 
    <img src="images/moon.jpg" id="Image2" alt="" style="width:204px;height:200px;">
</div>
<div id="Text1" style="position:absolute;left:109px;top:236px;width:232px;height:76px;z-index:3;‌​text-align:left;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:'Arial Black';font-size:27px;">We went to the moon!</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Image1 { border: 0px #000000 solid; } 
#Image2 { border: 0px #000000 solid; } 
#Text1 { 
    background-color: transparent; 
    border: 0px #000000 solid; 
    padding: 0; 
    text-align: left; 
} 
#Text1 div { text-align: left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5t3L/

Fiddle - updated text colour so it's easier to see

Comment: I believe both images can be achieved with css, it's basically on hover, change container size

Comment: Just change the size of the image on `:hover` and to keep the aspect ratio, change say `width: 100px` while `height: auto`

Comment: @Huangism , could you give me some sample code perhaps? I wanna make sure I get the ids & classes & all that right when I use the :hover

Comment: @TheBokiya , that isn't one image, it's an image with another image div on it & a text div. I know how to make one div by itself do this.

Comment: @user3082724 post the code you have so far and perhaps we can correct it

Comment: @Huangism , it's useless, it's only for one div, I have no idea how to connect one div's changes to another that's on it. That's basically what I'm asking. In a video editor I would just make one layer of video the parent of another, but I don't know how to do that in code.

Comment: @user3082724 you put the hover on the container so `#container` will target it normally and `#container:hover` will target it for hover. If you have items that are children of #container then `#container:hover div` or whatever the items are

Comment: Bod
<div id="Image1" style="position:absolute;left:72px;top:176px;width:515px;height:250px;z-index:0;">
<img src="images/camobg.jpg" id="Image1" alt="" style="width:515px;height:250px;"></div>
<div id="Image2" style="position:absolute;left:372px;top:205px;width:204px;height:200px;z-index:1;">
<img src="images/moon.jpg" id="Image2" alt="" style="width:204px;height:200px;"></div>
<div id="Text1" style="position:absolute;left:109px;top:236px;width:232px;height:76px;z-index:3;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:'Arial Black';font-size:27px;">We went to the moon!</span></div>

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#Image1
{
   border: 0px #000000 solid;
}
#Image2
{
   border: 0px #000000 solid;
}

#Text1 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0px #000000 solid;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
#Text1 div
{
   text-align: left;
}
</style>

Comment: @Huangism , I can't get the code mini-markdown symbol from my keyboard only ~ so I had to post the code above of a test I have set up for this. I would've used the regular post to make it look better but I don't have enough reputation. This reputation stuff is starting to get to me.

Comment: @user3082724 fear not, I have posted the code for you

Comment: Here is a simple example on how to target stuff inside of the container http://jsfiddle.net/L5t3L/1/

Comment: @Huangism it isn't doing anything, I copy/pasted your fiddle code in my notepad++ over the old segment of code & it doesn't resize.

Comment: @user3082724 does the fiddle work for you? as in can you see the red bordered box resizing on hover

Comment: @Huangism 
 
I can see the red border box resize on hover, but that doesn't help me much in notepad++ with the actual images & text. :(

Comment: @user3082724 you just target those elements the same way I am targeting the red box and do what you need to do

Comment: @Huangism Ok, I got the image on top of the image to resize with that image on hover, but the text refuses to resize. CSS: #container { position: relative; height: 100%; } #container:hover #Text1 { width: 300px !important; height: 200px !important; } #container:hover #Image1 { width: 700px !important; height: auto !important; } #container:hover #Image2 { width: 300px !important; height: auto !important; }

Comment: @user3082724 If you meaning the font-size did not resize, then you need to adjsut the font-size when hovering and in the css you don't have anything like that

Comment: @Huangism I tried this & it didn't work CSS: #container:hover #Text1 {
        font-size: 50px !important;
        

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an element that contains everything you want to resize, use the `scale` transform on the containing element, like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccQ9Z/1/)

```
#container {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#container:hover {
   -ms-transform: scale(2,2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle works, but I have this weird hesitance to use CSS3. I got one div by itself to resize on hover without CSS3, can I do this with regular CSS?

Comment: You could use jquery animate and specify the properties you want changed.  Note that the text changing size only works if it inherits font-size.  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccQ9Z/3/)

Comment: you could also use the jqeuryui extension that allows animating class changes [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccQ9Z/4/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those things :)

Comment: If you want to use that with your existing setup, you'll need to move more of the style away from the html to the css, and make the elements dimensions relative to their parent, a bit like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5t3L/2/)

Comment: hey thanks, I just might go that route. Is there a way to get that fiddle to resize from the center instead of the left?

Comment: Sure, adjust the `left` and `top` as well.  If it is both getting larger and sliding up to the left, at the same rate, it will appear to be expanding from the center.  The trick will be to reduce left and top by half the difference in width and height, respectively, so that the center ends up not moving.